# nanfunctions and regular functions behaving the same on Pandas type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

Normally `numpy.var()` is different than `numpy.nanvar()` when there are missing values, the same for `numpy.std()` and `numpy.nanstd()`. However:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,np.NaN,np.NaN,np.NaN]})

print("np.var() " + " : "+ str(np.var(df["A"])))
print("np.nanvar() " + " : "+ str(np.nanvar(df["A"])))
print("np.std() " + " : "+ str(np.std(df["A"])))
print("np.nanstd() " + " : "+ str(np.nanstd(df["A"])))
```

Results:

```
np.var() : 8.25
np.nanvar() : 8.25
np.std() : 2.8722813232690143
np.nanstd() : 2.8722813232690143
```

Why are both the same? There is nothing about missing values in the documentation of `np.var()` or `np.std()`.

Comment: It has to do with it being a pandas Series. If you did `np.var(df["A"].tolist())` you would get `nan`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because `numpy.std` (resp. `numpy.var`) tries to delegate to the first argument's `std` (resp. `var`) method if it isn't an ndarray (from [source code here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py#L2857)):

```
def std(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, ddof=0, keepdims=np._NoValue):
    kwargs = {}
    if keepdims is not np._NoValue:
        kwargs['keepdims'] = keepdims

    if type(a) is not mu.ndarray:
        try:
            std = a.std
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        else:
            return std(axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof, **kwargs)

    return _methods._std(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, ddof=ddof,
                         **kwargs)
```

So really, you're just calling [`pandas.Series.std`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.std.html) (with 0 degrees of freedom). And in the Pandas library, all of the descriptive stats functions handle missing values (from docs see [Calculations with missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#calculations-with-missing-data)).

The takeaway here is that it is a lot more clear to use the Pandas data type methods instead of the NumPy free functions in the first place, given you have a Pandas Series.

---

#### Comments

This behavior is what NumPy does for many functions with an array-like object as a first argument - try to use the same method on the object should it exist, and if not use some fallback. It isn't always the case though - for instance

```
>>> a = np.random.randint(0, 100, 5)

>>> a
array([49, 68, 93, 51, 94])

>>> np.sort(a) # not in-place
array([49, 51, 68, 93, 94])

>>> a
array([49, 68, 93, 51, 94])

>>> a.sort() # in-place

>>> a
array([49, 51, 68, 93, 94])
```

Also, in most cases the NaN handling functions in [`nanfunctions.py`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py) first call `_replace_nan`, which casts your type to an ndarray, and replaces the NaN values in your ndarray with a value that won't affect whatever calculation they are performing (i.e. `np.nansum` replaces NaNs with 0, `np.nanprod` replaces NaNs with 1). They then call their non-NaN counterparts to perform the actual calculation. (ex: [`np.nansum`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7210768d8da23cea34c2f2cf05cdfb8837542e3c/numpy/lib/nanfunctions.py#L495))

```
def nansum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue):
    a, mask = _replace_nan(a, 0)
    return np.sum(a, axis=axis, dtype=dtype, out=out, keepdims=keepdims)
```

So calling `np.nansum` on a Pandas series for instance, you don't actually end up using `pandas.Series.sum` because the Series is cast to an ndarray first inside `_replace_nan`. So don't (I'm not sure why you would) assume or rely on the `sum` method of your Series being called.

```
# a silly example

>>> s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])

>>> s.sum = lambda *args, **kwargs: "instance sum"

>>> s.sum()
'instance sum'

>>> np.sum(s)
'instance sum'

>>> np.nansum(s)
6
```

Comment: Is this true *in general* for `numpy` functions, e.g. `nanmean`? Not expecting you to go through all the source code, but just want to know if this is a general case where `np.func(var)` attempts `var.func()` first if possible.

Comment: @jpp I added a bit more info to my answer. But yeah in general, if you aren't sure I'd say check, and don't rely on it being the case. AFAIK there isn't some characterization for all the free functions that behave like this.